# One class naive bayes

Tags: naive-bayes-classifier

I have to build one class naive Bayes method for outlier detection based on the likelihood probabilities. I tried to create it using sklearn GaussianNB but it is for multiclass classification. Is there any way to do it in python or Matlab?

Comment: Can't a one-class classification also be converted to a binary classification? Sure there must some data augmentation that you can do here?

Comment: I have to compare the results with some other one class methods like one class SVM etc so I am looking for one class Bayes method.